# Dynamically Assign Variables after looping through JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Probably a beginner question, but I have an array json object that I'm looping through to pull out certain values.  If these values equal "NO", then I want to hide a div using jquery.  This should be simple enough, but I don't know how many items the array can contain so I'll have to make sure to dynamically grab all of the number/value pairs.

My JSON is similar to below:

```
"account" : [{
    "ID":1,
    "transferAllowed": "NO"
},{
    "ID":2,
    "transferAllowed": "YES"
}]
```

My loop:

```
//define variable that references the values I need from the json object
var account = this.json.account;

 for ( var i = 0; i < account.length; i++ ) {
    //compare all values of transferAllowed however many that may be.  If they all equal No, then hide div with jquery $("#div").hide()

}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: As an incidental comment on this code, it's probably not a good habit to declare `var i` inside the `for` statement like that. Unlike some languages, a loop does not have its own variable scope, so `var i` is still declaring a variable for the whole function - including lines *above* the declaration (a confusing effect known as "hoisting").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flipping the problem, like defining a "null hypothesis" for a science experiment: to *disprove* that all items say "NO", you need only find a single value that *doesn't* say "NO".

This means that you only need a simple check in the loop to find your answer:

```
var account = this.json.account;
// Start with the hypothesis that everything will say "NO"
var allDisallowed = true;

for ( var i = 0; i < account.length; i++ ) {
    if ( account[i].transferAllowed != "NO" ) {
         // Hypothesis disproved!
         allDisallowed = false;
    }
}

if ( allDisallowed ) {
    $("#div").hide();
}
```

Since you only need *one* value to be allowed, you can actually stop at the first one you see using a `break;` statement:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < account.length; i++ ) {
    if ( account[i].transferAllowed != "NO" ) {
         // Hypothesis disproved!
         allDisallowed = false;
         // No need to finish the loop
         break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you wrap the loop up in a function, you can save defining some variables:

```
function areAllDisallowed( account ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < account.length; i++ ) {
        if ( account[i].transferAllowed != "NO" ) {
             // At least one element is not a "NO", so result is false
             return false;
        }
    }
    // We will only reach this line if we never return false
    // Therefore, we know that all elements say "NO"
    return true;
}

if ( areAllDisallowed(this.json.account) ) {
    $("#div").hide();
}
```

(As pointed out in a comment, the position of `var i` in the `for` loop could cause confusion later, but I've left it as-is to make only the changes that answer your specific question.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!  I didn't even consider thinking about flipping the problem.

Comment: Your second solution with exiting the loop once a value of something other than "NO" is found made the most sense to me.  So far, it seems to be working in my application.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
var account    = this.json.account;
var hide_count = 0;
for ( var i = 0; i < account.length; i++ ) {
   if(account[i].transferAllowed=="NO") hide_count++;
}
if(hide_count == account.length){
   $("#div").hide();  
}
```